# PUT request without id

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication

I have an API method where the authentication server allows an automatic registration when the user does not exist yet on first login.

The auth server would make a call to:

```
PUT https://some-api/api/v1/auth/users
```

The handler of this method will check if the user already exists, and create it when the user does not based on email.
My question is whether there is something inherently wrong with not specifying the id in url upfront. The problem being that in fact, there is no userId yet when the user does not exist.
I know that the usual format would be:

```
PUT https://some-api/api/v1/auth/users/:userId
```

Obviously the client can check whether the user exists based on email upfront, create a POST request to create the user, or GET if the user already exists.
This introduces more network requests so I'd prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is some common solution to use 'email' as resource identifier.

This works for me. One remark is that I do not particularly like to use an email address in the url, but in my case it is okay as this url will only be visible within the cluster, and is not exposed to the outside network.